# Removing whitespace from an 'if else' block with eclipse formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I currently have Eclipse formatter set up to format an 'if-else' statement like so:

```
if(condition) {
  return foo;
}
else{
  return bar;
}
```

Note the space between the closing parenthesis of the condition, and the opening bracket of the true block - I'd like to remove this space.

In the formatter profile, under `Whitespace -> Control statements -> 'if else'`, there is no option for 'after closing parenthesis'. In the `Blocks` section, there is an option for 'before opening brace', however this appears to only apply to the false block (and is turned off anyway).

I must be missing an option somewhere - how can I turn this whitespace off?

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0.

Comment: In Luna, unchecking the `before opening brace` in blocks removes the whitespace properly. Could very well be a bug in Mars. Not sure though.

Comment: I know that source code layout is a delicate subject. But why do you want to format your code like this?

Comment: Ahh, yeah I booted up Luna, and it appears the 'before opening brace' option in blocks works there - so this must be a bug in Mars.

Comment: @EricGärtner I want to format my code like that because that's how I prefer it?

Comment: @Numeron So you work as a single developer, not in a team?

Comment: Can you check my updated answer.

Comment: @EricGärtner I use this profile for my personal work, but everyone has different preferences for code style, and there is no right or wrong. I like compact code, the guy who sits behind me at work likes spread out code. 6 of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: But how to you share code in a team if every developer formats the code in a different way? How do you prevent endless merging of trivial changes in format?

Comment: IMO the only single golden rule of formatting is that the whole project should be consistent - so everyone needs to use the same format.. Perhaps I was a little unclear though - This is for my personal work, the formatter I use professionally is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [Eclipse Bug # 471145](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471145) (specific to Mars / 4.5.0), which was reported on 2015-06-26, [fixed](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/commit/?id=5cdaf7a24addcdf2556ae50d4248faab4b628186) on 2015-08-01, and will be included in [Eclipse 4.5.1](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/freeze_plan_4_5_1.php) - which should be complete and ready for download by the end of September 2015 as part of the [Mars coordinated service release](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mars).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style ->formatter -> Edit profile section

[image]

---

I think it does once you select the other option in drop down that you can see below

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in your screenshot, an "after closing parenthesis" option doesn't exist

Comment: Can you check now ? --- Dropdown -> Sort options by Syntax element

Comment: Oh wow yeah, it was there and that worked - not sure why the option is missing from the 'if else' section.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > White Space` and in `Control statements > Blocks`, unselect the "before opening brace" option :)

[image]

Comment: This is correct for Luna (which I just tested) - It seems the reason it's not working for me must be because of a bug in Mars

Comment: Oh, ok. Is it possible for you to update your Eclipse version ? :)